# Is it possible to pass a standard ado connection string to Invoke-SqlCmd

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Is it possible to use a connection string like:

```
Data Source=[server];Initial Catalog=[database];Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

or:

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=[database];Data Source=[server];uid=[username];pwd=[password];Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=10;Max Pool Size=500;Incr Pool Size=5;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

with `Invoke-Sqlcmd`?

Comment: [Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time this question was asked, no. More recently, yes, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` now supports a `-ConnectionString` parameter that accepts a standard database connection string as a value.

Previously, you'd need to break out each of the parameters in your connection string and match them up with the parameters that `Invoke-Sqlcmd` accepts.

If you had the flexibility and are stuck with a frozen legacy environment, you may wish to bodge Chad Miller's `Invoke Sqlcmd2` and make it accept an ADO.NET connection string as one of its parameters:

> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7985b7ef-ed89-4dfd-b02a-433cc4e30894

Comment: Ok I suspected from the documentation, but had a small hope for an undocumented feature. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Actually, Yes.

As of this writing the `invoke-sqlcmd` available in the [SQLServer](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17152) module includes a `-connectionString` parameter.

Comment: Confirming that it works. Just makes sure to remove old "SQLPS" PowerShell module that contains another version of `Invoke-sqlcmd` that does not support full control over connection string.